# Массив в JS является псевдоложью?

Tags: javascript

Задаю данный вопрос, так как пишут, что [] -не является псевдоложью,но ведь:

```
console.log([] - true); // -1
console.log([] == true); // false 
let emptyArr =[]
if(emptyArr)
console.log('true')// true

let emptyArr =[]
if(emptyArr && emptyArr == true)
console.log('true')// false
```

Вроде пишут только о 5 псевдоложных значения или это старая инфа?
Вообще мне конечно нравится выражения, типа true - true = 0)))

Comment: `console.log([1] - true) // тут да, будет true` - вот тут будет 0, а не `true`

Comment: дай определение, что такое "псевдоложь"?

Comment: Псевдоложь в Javascript это значение, по факту не являющиеся true и false, но принимаемые за true и false в условных выражениях

Comment: @Grundy это, как альтернативные факты:)

Comment: @October, условное выражение это `if`, поэтому некорректно рассматривать `==`, `-`, и т.д. можно смотреть только `if([])`

Comment: Grundy, разве if(a==b) - это не условное выражение? я считал, что операторы могут являться частью условия. Почему некорректно рассматривать ==, -?

Answer (score 3):

Ответ в сниппете:

```js
let emptyArr = []
if(emptyArr)
  console.log('нет')
```

Демонстрация как работает приведение массива и булевого типа к числу, которое используется, когда вы применяете вычитание:

```js
console.log(+[] ); // 0;
console.log(+[1]); // 1;
console.log(+[2]); // 2;
console.log(+[2,2]); // NaN;
console.log(+true ); // 1;
```

Comment: В выше приведенном  коде, условие выполняется, так как оно истинно, но что если код будет таким:                                                                                                                                                  let emptyArr = [];
if (emptyArr && emptyArr == true){
 console.log('нет');
}//оно не выполнится, я просто пытаюсь понять!

Comment: @October == приводит правый и левый операнд к number, если их типы не совпадают

Comment: Так, а если "===" или он тоже преобразует типы?

Comment: Stranger in the Q , спасибо за уделенное внимание

Comment: @October нет, тройное равно не преобразует типы, и в консоли с ним ничего не будет напечатано.

Comment: Stranger in the Q, как то не явно с [], c null все просто, в любом случае будет ложь.